# Accumarray with non-scalar subscripts in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `m x 3`, e.g. `m=18`

```
A=[ 2| 1 1;
    3| 1 2;
   -8| 1 3;
   -------
   -5| 1 1;
    2| 1 2;
    6| 1 3;
   -------
    7| 2 1;
    3| 2 2;
    1| 2 3;
    5| 2 4;
   -------
    3| 2 1;
   -8| 2 2;
    1| 2 3;
    0| 2 4;
   -------
    1| 2 1;
    2| 2 2;
    7| 2 3;
    9| 2 4]
```

The characteristics of `A` are the following:

1. It is composed by `t` submatrices. In the example `t=5`.
2. Each submatrix `t` has dimension `b x 3` with `b<=m` and `b` can take any value in `{3,4,5,...,m}` (clearly, in a way such that the sum of all rows is `m`). In the example, the first and the second submatrices have dimension `3 x 3`, the last three submatrices have dimension `4 x 3`.
3. All submatrices of the same dimension are stacked one after the other. In the example, firstly we have the submatrices `3 x 3` and then the submatrices `4 x 3`.

I want to compute the vector `B` of dimension `f x 1` where `f=size(unique(A(:,2:end),'rows','stable'),1)`, (in the example `f=7`), such that `B(i,1)` is obtained by summing the elements `j` of `A(:,1)` having `A(j,2:end)` equal to the `i`-th row of `unique(A(:,2:end),'rows','stable')`, i.e.

```
B=[2-5;
   3+2;
  -8+6
   7+3+1;
   3-8+2;
   1+1+7;
   5+0+9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the third output of `unique` when examining `A` over the rows and with the `'stable'` flag, then use this as input into `accumarray`.  The third output assigns a unique ID for each unique occurrence of a row vector seen in your matrix `A`, which is very suitable for use in `accumarray`:

```
[~,~,f] = unique(A(:,2:end), 'rows', 'stable');
B = accumarray(f, A(:,1));
```

We get:

```
B =

    -3 %// 2-5
     5 %// 3+2
    -2 %// -8+6
    11 %// 7+3+1
    -3 %// 3-8+2
     9 %// 1+1+7
    14 %// 5+0+9
```